# GCP: How to access VM in shared VPC by Hostname

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have HostProject & Service Project

I have done network peering using shared VPC.

I'm able to access my Host Project VM from Service Project by Internal IP address.

How can I access by hostname instead of IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There is only two type of internal DNS names **[Zonal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#zonal-dns)** and **Global (project wide) DNS**.

I think this is what you are looking for, you can use a Private DNS zone with shared VPC, see the [Google Public Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#shared-vpc) on how to do it.